# Invoice PDF Not supports Arabic characters : Magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf

I have a problem in Arabic encoding in invoice pdf print ( alaways appears like squares), but I found this library :
https://github.com/rossmc/SalesPdfFonts

But Arabic characters are separated and reversed

Can any body help

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue in Zend_pdf I would recommend you to use TCPDF here is the link for that http://www.tcpdf.org/

Go through there examples

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

If you still want to stick with zend pdf may this link be helpful.

http://devzone.zend.com/1064/zend_pdf-tutorial/

Have you tried this?
https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-arabic-language-pack
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-arabic-language-pack.html

Comment: Thank you, How can I integrate TCPDF tp integrate invoice PDF ??

Comment: Hi, @Jsparo30  do you got a solution for integrate TCPDF for invoice PDF?  Please share the solution here

Comment: Hi @AskBytes, Sorry, I didn't find.